# Python creating handler for an object?

Tags: python, handler

I'm trying to create a handler which triggers whenever any of object's attributes' value changes. I'm still quite new with python, and didn't really come up with any working ways. This is what I did, and I know it can't work like this, it's just to show what I'm trying to achieve:

```
# ../handler.py
import copy

class Handler:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        # Let the object know it's handler
        obj.handler = self

        # Copy the object
        self.copy = copy.deepcopy(obj)

        # Let handler know it's object
        self.obj = obj

        # Handler not running atm.
        self.running = False

def start(self):
    # Running
    self.running = True

    # As long as running...
    while self.running:

        # Loop through all objects attributes
        for attr in self.obj.__dict__:

            # If attribute's value has changed
            if self.copy.__dict__[attr] != self.obj.__dict__[attr]:

                # Print out a message
                print("%s was changed to %s" %(attr, self.obj.__dict__[attr]))

                # Update the value to our copy
                self.copy.__dict__[attr] = self.obj.__dict__[attr]

def stop(self):
    # Not running
    self.running = False
```

Here's the main file

```
# ../main.py
from handler import Handler

class Value:
    def __init__(self, v=None):
        self.value = v

def createObject(v):
    obj = Value(v)
    Handler(obj)
    return obj

myObj = createObject(5)
myObj.handler.start()
```

This will, however, result into this text getting printed out: `handler was changed to <Handler.Handler object at 0x0000000002B1FC50>` but I'm not changing the handler here? Also, the program will freeze, due to the while loop inside the Handler.start() function... How could I implement this in a working way?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why is the program printing out "handler was changed to ...", and how could I make the program not to infinite loop to the Handler.start() ?

Comment: “What is the problem you're trying to solve?” is asking you to state a high-level goal, rather than some low-level goal that may be unrelated to what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively want a proxy, and here's a bit of a start...

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        object.__setattr__(self, '__obj', obj)
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return getattr(object.__getattribute__(self, '__obj'), name)


a = range(10)
p = Proxy(a)

p.append(10) # etc...
```

You'll also need to look for `__setattribute__` and `__delattribute__` and other magic methods...

How you'd cater for when the attribute changes could be a bit trickier - as you'd have to know if method calls existed which changed the object inplace... (such as `append` above)

A quick Google comes up with: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/

Comment: Hmm thanks, never heard of such a term used in programming... Will get into it :)

Comment: I wouldn't accept the answer quick so quickly - there's no rush, and others may come up with better!

Comment: Uh, wtf O.o First time anyone ever saying not to accept their answer... Well, I'll un-accept then, maybe I'll learn something new :) But couldn't find much with "python handler" from google, and "python proxy" gave me much more info, so this is basically enough for me to search all the info I need.

Comment: edit: Found everything I needed from google, got it working now, thanks. :)

Comment: There is no such datamodel hook as `__delattribute__`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Proxier(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        obj.handler = self

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.obj, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key != 'obj':
            oldvalue = getattr(self.obj, key)
            if oldvalue != value:
                doSomething()

            setattr(self.obj, key, value)
        else:
            setattr(self, key, value)

class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, v=None):
        self.value = v

myObj = Proxier(Value(2))
```